# Problemas con el ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

He implementado un scroll para mi layout de registro de usuarios, y al momento de ejecutar la app no me funciona el scroll, también me genera un espaciado por abajo, como un margin_botom y no me deja jalar más abajo mis elementos que están dentro del Constraint_Layout.

***Aqui una imagen del problema**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***activity_registrar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.RegistrarActivity"
android:layout_margin="20dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/usuario"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_proyecto1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nombres y Apellidos:"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_boton"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbNombre" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="265dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Email:"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_boton"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbSexo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Sexo:"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_boton"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbSexo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbContrasenia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Contraseña:"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_boton"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbContrasenia" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbRepitaContrasenia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Repita la contraseña:"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText7" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_boton"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbRepitaContrasenia" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkAceptoTerminos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Acepto los terminos y condiciones"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnRegistrar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegistrar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/boton_registrar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Registrar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Prueba poniendo el Constraint_Layout dentro del ScrollView.

Comment: Desde un inicio el constraint_layout ya estaba dentro del ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la ventana de `Text` elimina los `app:layout`, esto para que puedas manipularlos en
la ventana de `Design`. Lo ideal es tener un `id` a cada view, de todas maneras sino los
tiene al momento de restringirlo (Constraint) Android Studio le asigna uno.

Suponiendo que el EditText que esta despues del textView lbRepitaContrasenia sea:

```
 android:id="@+id/editText8"
```

El checkbox debe quedar restringido debajo de ese editText:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText8"
```

y el boton `android:id="@+id/btnRegistrar"` debajo de ese checkbox:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chkAceptoTerminos"
```

Comment: Para ser sincero, tu respuesta me ayudo a entender más del constraint_layout y el problema real era solo el botón que lo habia puesto accidentalmente junto a otro elemento que no me permitia desplazarlo más abajo.